# Multiple View Controllers, am I screwed?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

When I first started this iPhone app, I was still a beginner so I was taking code from samples.

I have 4 Views (UIView) with 4 View Controllers (UiViewContorllers). They all sit on the same level in Interface Builder.

UiViewA is the main Menu, and it has buttons that when pressed loads ViewB,C,D via addSubView:ViewB(c/d/etc) . I am running into a problem now that only ViewA's ViewController is getting all the messages and notifications.

Am I screwed here? Should I have NOT been adding subviews of ViewB,C,D directly from ViewA?
Should I have been loading the ViewController instead?

What work around do I have ?

So far, I have been transforming the other views directly if I wanted rotation.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track: loading the UIViewController instead of the UIView should solve this for you.  You can accomplish this as follows (from your first UIViewController):

```
[self presentModalViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
```

This will slide another UIViewController up over your current view and preserve its lifecycle and logic.  Hope this helps!